# jQuery animation - move a box by coordinates

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a `<div>` with `position: absolute`:

```
<div style="top:200px; left:400px;">
```

and I want it nicely and slowly be moved to new coordinates e.g.:

```
<div style="top:100px; left:500px;">
```

Which jQuery animation effect can do this? Or is there a other solution?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using animate function after you have set initial position as absolute. On the other hand you can copy the div and remove the original and then move it to new coordinate using animate function from jQuery.

```
jQuery(".container").click(function() {

var position1 = jQuery("#position1").position();
alert(position1.top + ', ' + position1.left);

var position2 = jQuery(this).position();
alert(position2.top + ', ' + position2.left);

});
```

and then

```
$('.container').click(function(){
    var position1 = $('#position1').position();

    $(this).animate({ 'top': position1.top + 'px', 'left': position1.left + 'px'}, 150, function(){

    });
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Javascript to animate something as simple as this. It can be easily done with CSS.

Comment: @ David Wester how? Just CSS?

Comment: have a look at this link https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_movement_smoothly_using_css.htm

Comment: @BhimeshChauhan is there any chance to specify the trajectory of movement? Let's say I want to have the arc movement. Is it possible?

Comment: @AlexF I think there are multiple ways to do that. However, cleaner way according to my knowledge is written by tobias. link - http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/

Comment: @BhimeshChauhan I will mark your answer as a solution since I already implemented it and it works fine. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use jQuery animate for this. It is way easier to do with CSS, and it also looks a lot smoother.

You create a class that has the following attributes:

```
.animate{
    transform: translate(50px, 100px);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

the first value in `translate()` is the amount of pixels to move to right, and the second is the amount of pixels to move down.

So if we use the example you gave us, it should be:

```
.animate{
    transform: translate(100px, -100px);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

the `1s` on `transition` is the total amount of seconds the animation will take. You can use decimals here.

The `ease-in-out` is the way the animation is going to animate. You can find a complete list [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp).

When you want the animation to start you simply add the class to div. The following code will add the class to the div when you click on it:

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $("div").addClass("animate");
});
```

You do need to change the selectors, right now it will do it will work on every `div` in your page.

Comment: That's amazing solution but unfortunately I can't use it. Opera mini doesn't support "transition" while I'm doing mobile oriented project. Anyway lots of thanks for you efforts!

Comment: @AlexF Yeah, Opera Mini is even worse then IE. I don't support it anymore, since only about 0.5% of all my traffic came from opera Mini. and instead I show a message that they should another browser, but I can understand it if you don't want to use it, since, according to CanIuse, 5% of Internet user use Opera Mini.